An csv file with 200 columns in adls. fetch only list of columns from config table. config table is in Azure SQL. config table has only 10 col names
An csv file with 200 columns in adls. fetch only the list of columns from the config table. config table is in Azure SQL.config table has only 10 column names. how to create pipeline with this scenario in Azure datafactory?
Created a Lookup activity to fetch column names from the Azure SQL config table.
Added a ForEach activity to iterate over the column names.
Inside the ForEach activity, created a variable to store the current column name.
Added a Copy activity to filter the CSV file based on the current column name.
it is not working.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You can use Dataflow activity to copy the required 10 columns from a 200-columns CSV file to an Azure SQL table. Follow the procedure below according to your requirements:

Use Look UP activity to list the columns of the SQL table named Config, separated by commas, using the query below:

SELECT STRING_AGG(COLUMN_NAME, ',') AS ColumnNames
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Config';

This will produce the output as shown below:


Create a Dataflow as follows:

Add an ADLS file with 200 columns as the source.
Add a Select activity to the Select transformation for the source.
Choose the Rule-based mapping option by clicking +Add mapping.
Go to the expression builder, create a string parameter columnlist, and use the expression below to select the required columns from the file:



contains(split($columnlist,','), #item==name)



Add a Sink transformation to the Select transformation and select the SQL table as the Sink dataset.
Publish the Dataflow.
Add a Dataflow activity to the Lookup activity, select the above Dataflow, and pass the Lookup output to the previously created parameter columnlist. Select the pipeline expression option and use the dynamic expression below:

@activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.ColumnNames



Debug the pipeline. The required columns' data will be copied into the SQL table successfully, as shown below:


